# TeX: Figures ending up in references?

Tags: bibtex, floats

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\includegraphics[width=0.50\textwidth]{review.png} 
\caption{Product Reviews literature background} 
\label{fig:rev} 
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\includegraphics[width=0.50\textwidth]{class.png} 
\caption{Classification literature background} 
\label{fig:class} 
\end{figure}



\bibliographystyle{plain}%Used BibTeX style is unsrt
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

The above shows the syntax of my latex-code. However, my figures end up in the reference list itself -in the middle of it all. What can I do?

I tried adding [htbp] and [!hb] to all figures, but nothing works.

I have 8 figures, the first 2 aligns where they should be, the remaining 6 just spreads out over the reference list? How is this even possible when its imported from bibtex?

Comment: note that you made it more likely that the figures floated away (and into the references) as your optional argument prevented the figures being placed in almost all places, `[h]` means do not place the figures at top or bottom of a text page or on a page of floats.  That means that the most likely outcome is the figure floats to the end of the document as it is not allowed anywhere. In fact after the first page break latex assumes you didn't mean `h` and warns it is changing it to `ht` but even that is very restrictive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, right as I posted, I found the answer.

```
\clearpage
```

helped me out, forcing the references to start on the next page instead of the same. Compromise, but it works.

Comment: This isn't a lot of information to go by. Are you issuing one or more `\clearpage` instructions? Where are they occurring -- before or after certain `figure` environments?

Comment: I entered the \clearpage command right after the figured, inbetween the last \end{figure} and the bibliography